# how to dry up these tests with jasmine.js

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, coffeescript, jasmine

I have a lot of tests like the following :

```
it "Should call togglePadding if df-padding is checked", ->
        spyOn(App.columnsSetupBuildingBlockController.content, 'togglePadding')
        App.view.set("paddingChecked", null)

        Em.run ->
            App.view.set("paddingChecked", true)

        expect(App.columnsSetupBuildingBlockController.content.togglePadding).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true)

    it "Should call togglePadding if df-padding is unchecked", ->
        spyOn(App.columnsSetupBuildingBlockController.content, 'togglePadding')
        App.view.set("paddingChecked", true)

        Em.run ->
            App.view.set("paddingChecked", null)

        expect(App.columnsSetupBuildingBlockController.content.togglePadding).toHaveBeenCalledWith(null)
```

There is only a fews different values in each test that are different.   How can i write a shared function to dry up the duplicated bits and make it look a lot cleaner ?

I also have the same tests for testing margin, border etc

Please help.

Thanks
Rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure I am missing something in your question ... but this is what I understood you want to do

```
setup = (mode = null)->
    value1 = mode
    value2 = if not mode then true else null
    spyOn(App.columnsSetupBuildingBlockController.content, 'togglePadding')
    App.view.set("paddingChecked", value1)

    Em.run ->
        App.view.set("paddingChecked", value2)

    expect(App.columnsSetupBuildingBlockController.content.togglePadding).toHaveBeenCalledWith(value2)

it "Should call togglePadding if df-padding is checked", ->
    setup null

it "Should call togglePadding if df-padding is unchecked", ->
    setup true
```